# Extraposition -examples

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> a. Some guy with red hair was there.
>
> b. Some guy was there with red hair.

Do both these sentences express the same meaning? I saw it in Wikipedia as examples of extraposition.

Comment: The second sounds odd to me: it sounds like the hair is separate from the guy (who may or may not have had red hair).

Comment: @PeterK, yes, it sounds like this guy was bringing someone's red hair with him ;)

Comment: Or: "Some guy was there with red hair; yesterday he was blond."

Comment: More or less, but there's no 'extraposition' here. Wiki us just being silly about this. Your b. example is about **postposing**, where the PP "with red hair" is postposed to the end of the clause. 'Extraposition involves moving a subordinate clause subject to the end of the clause and replacing it with the dummy pronoun "it".